# JSHint thinks Jest functions are undefined

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jshint, jestjs

I have a node.js project in WebStorm IDE that contains a simple Jest test.
The test pass but JSHint warns that `'test' is not defined (w117)`.

[image]

Here is my test code:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Is there any way to make JSHint recognize Jest functions?

Comment: would you mind showing us your code?

Comment: Added the test code

Comment: Alright and where did you define / require / import `test`?

Comment: jest does this implicitly when running tests. Similar to how browsers always define document for you.

Answer (score 3):

**JSHint** works on per-file basis and doesn't 'see' global variables defined in other files unless they are added to 'global' list. This can be done by either adding the corresponding comments (`/* global test*/`) to your files - see http://www.jshint.com/docs/, or by adding variables/functions you'd like to use globally to the 'Predefined' list in `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Code Quality Tool -> JSHint -> Predefined (,separated)`. If you are using your own `.jshintrc` (**Use config files** option is enabled), add it to "globals" there:

```
"globals": {
    "test": true
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code you are showing us, one can only assume, that `test()` is an implicitly declared global variable.

At this point I don't know which framework this method belongs to, but if you want JSHint to shut up about it, you have to somehow declare that variable:

```
import test from { 'somemodule'}
//or
var test = require('test');
//or
(function(test){
    test('foo', () => {
         expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
})(test);
```

If you know what you are doing, you can disable that warning, with one of the following ways:

Confgigure .jshintrc.json file in your project folder or above:

```
{
  "undef": false
}
```

Or you can disable that warning inline by using

```
/*jshint -W117 */
test('foo', () => { /* ... */})
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be caused by a missing dependency.

Make sure you've installed `@types/jest`

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jest
```